# Want to download jQuery using Python, but not able to do so

Tags: jquery, python-2.7

I attempted to install jQuery using `pip install jquery`, but received this error:

```
> pip install jquery

Collecting jquery
  Downloading jquery-1.2.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-id644a/jquery/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        from turbogears.finddata import find_package_data
    ImportError: No module named turbogears.finddata

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-jvdejr/jquery/
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Seriously ? what is this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have a Python Package distribution. The one you're trying to access in your question is [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jquery/1.2.3), related to another package, TurboGears.

If possible, don't use `pip install` to obtain jQuery. Use `npm` instead (requires [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/)):

```
$ npm install -g jquery
```

or [bower](https://bower.io/):

```
$ bower install jquery
```

Or just download the latest distribution from [here](https://code.jquery.com/).